# Can I increase the volume of *Read out Loud* in my Adobe Reader?

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, adobe-reader, audio

I have Adobe Reader V 10.1.8 on my laptop and it has a *Read Out Loud* feature that reads the text in the e-book. The problem is that the volume is too low to hear what the reader is reading. Even with my laptop volume at 100% this is a problem.

Is there an application I can use or another way I can manually increase the volume of the *Read out Loud* feature?

Comment: @JasonDown. Thanks for the edit. It really expressed my problem clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Adobe Reader's internal volume:

- Go to the `Edit` menu, then `Preferences...`.
- On the left, 2/3 of the way down, is the category `Reading`. Click on that.
- You should see a box labeled `Read Out Loud Options`.
- There is a `Volume` selector ranging from 1 to 10; make sure that is high enough.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. The volume was set to 4, I have increased it to 8 and can now hear clearly. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks a lot have been looking for this for a long time now.